# What is the best amount of starting capital such that the number of games played (by a player of a fair game) is maximized?

Tags: probability, random-walk, gambling

Assume we are a player in a fair game with expectation value $0$.
He starts the game with a total capital of $M_0$.
The Player is always betting the exact same amount $B$ and wins $2B$ with probability $50\%$ or looses $B$ with probability $50\%$. He starts the game with a total capital of $M_0$.

> How to determine the best value for $M_0$ as function of $B$, such
> that the number of games played is maximized.

Sure the bigger $M_0$ the better.
But is there something like a sweet-spot?
It is a one-dimensional random walk so it would make sense to choose a starting capital $M_0$ that is greater than the variance of the random walk $\sqrt{n}$, with a given number of steps $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

How does casinos or vending-machine operators  with a slight advantage in every game manage this problem?
Potentially they always have the risk of back luck or not?
How does the minimize this risk?

Any assistance or thoughts or explanations would be much appreciated.

Comment: The fact that a one-dimensional random walk with zero expectation returns to the origin is a very special property of that process. As soon as you introduce a non-zero expectation that property simply disappears.

Comment: I assume the player plays until his capital is zero. Suppose at $M_0=m_1$ starting capital the expected number of games is $g(m_1).$ Then if we start with capital $2g(m_1)$ the _minimum_ number of games is twice the expected number for $m_1,$ and the expected number is obviously even greater. I see no reason why there would ever be a "sweet spot" based on the game as described. Now if you said the player stopped when his capital is $0$ or when it is $L$, there may be a "sweet spot" between $0$ and $L.$

Comment: regarding the first comment: Isn't it so that if I have a slight advantage or disadvantage I can show that the random walk returns to a linear straight line with probability 1? So the property does not simply disappears it just changes or not?

Comment: regarding the second comment: ok you are referring to the stopping time when i have the condition to stop at zero or a fixed amount. But how does vending-machine operators approach this problem with a slight advantage (house edge)? Do they always have the risk to get ruined? Obviously yes. Do they just have an avg of played games until they refill the machine? So with a known number of avg played games, it is possible to set a starting capital such that its almost impossible to get ruined.

Comment: "returns to a linear straight line"? It never leaves the straight line, it just tends to go in one direction along that line. And the bias means you go from a case where you hit the origin eventually with probability 1, no matter where you start, to one where you hit the origin with some probability that depends on where you start and goes to zero as you move the starting point further away. It's the "probability 1" and "no matter where you start" parts that disappear.

Comment: If an individual machine runs out, so what? Maybe it has to shut down until someone can come and put a few coins in it so it can pay out the prizes. What the casino counts on is that they have the resources to lose thousands of games consecutively without running out, and the chance of that happening is astronomically low. It is a risk they are willing to take.

Comment: topic "straigt line": i am referring to this picture of a normal 1-dim-rw here https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWvgY.png . With a slight advantage the white line would have a slight positive slope. i would assume that we can proof that the random-walk crosses the line in future with probability 1, in analogy to your first comment.

Comment: OK, when you introduce a new line it helps to describe it first. It's typical to model a random walk going back and forth on a line, so we always have that line. Then there are graphs of the random walk, where there are many lines you can draw; the interesting ones on your graph are horizontal line (representing a return to the starting point) and a line that follows the expected gain. It is true that you cross the expected gain line eventually with probability $1.$ From the point of view of the casino, that is very good news.